# Prove that the set of all arithmetic progressions is a countable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just didn't have an idea of how to solve this problem.

Prove that the set of all arithmetic progressions is a countable.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3):

An arithmetic progressions is uniquely determined by its starting element and its common difference. Hence the set of all arithmetic progressions is in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: An arithmetic progression can be described by starting point and step, prove that the set of pairs of integers is countable.

Comment: This assumes that we talk about arithmetic progressions of *integers*. Of Course, without that assumption, the number would not be uncountable ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I believe you mean it would not be not-uncountable... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Each arithmetic progression, $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, is uniquely determined by its initial value, $a_1$, and its common difference, $a_2-a_1$. Therefore there is a bijection between $\mathbb Z^2$ and the set of all arithmetic progressions.